# to do a spot of fishing

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Context:

> Shetland is a windswept, barren archipelago a hundred or so miles
>   northeast of mainland Scotland’s northernmost tip. I fell in love with
>   Shetland when I was 16. I had gone there to photograph otters and I’ve
>   been visiting it regularly ever since. It’s very windy a lot of the
>   time and if it’s not raining it’s usually cloudy. However, when the
>   wind settles and the sun comes out, few places on Earth can beat it
>   for beauty. I took this photograph of my friend Henry on just one of
>   those days. Henry had offered to take me out on his boat around the
>   back of the island of Vaila **to do a spot of fishing**. It was flat
>   calm out at sea and that gave us the chance to go through this arch.

Question:

What does "to do a spot of fishing" mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> a spot of *something* *(BrE)*

means a *small bit* / *little bit* of something as in metaphorically a "*small spot*".

> *Spot of* tea?

is a common BrE question.

The sentence is saying they went to do "*a little bit of fishing*".